# X86 Intel Assembly Language - Prime Numbers

Tags: assembly, intel

I am trying to create the following pseudo-code using assembly language:

```
prime = true ;
divisor = 2 ;
while ( divisor < number ) {
    if ( the remainder of number / divisor is 0 ) {
       prime = false ; // we found a divisor which evenly divides number 
    } // so therefore number cannot be prime
    divisor = divisor + 1 ; // check the next divisor and keep looping
}
```

So far I have completed the following, however I am not sure if I am headed in the right direction. I am unsure about how to set the prime boolean variable to false nor how to increment the divisor variable every time the if condition is not met in the loop iteration.

```
section .data
; put your data in this section using
; db , dw, dd directions

number db 5
answer db 1 ; 1 means number is prime, 0 means number is not prime
section .bss

; put UNINITIALIZED data here using

section .text
     global _start

_start:
    mov esi, number ; get the offset of number into esi
keith: mov eax, 0 ; clear the entire eax register
    mov al, [esi] ; get the number from memory into al
    mov dl, al ; put it inside dl as well
    mov bl, 2 ; bl holds each divisor starting from 2
loopy: div bl ; ax / bl with quot in al and rem in ah
    and ax, 1111111100000000b ; isolate the rem in ah with a AND mask
                    ; to determine whether the remainder is 0
```

Comment: You can use a number in some register as true/false for primer...

Comment: To play with conditions, look on jump instructions, http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/Jcc.html

Comment: Usually it is done like this:  perform some operation and in right register and result is used to skip some part of code or jump to specific point to do next iteration...

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/150779/110284 (you didn't work hard enough on your algorithm part)

Comment: The code doesn't need to `and ax`, instead it can use `or ah,ah` to check if ah == 0.